# Open target.html page within SAME window following successful login

Tags: javascript, html

After inputting login details i would like the target.html page to load in the same window. Currently it loads in a new tab.

```html
<body>
  <div class="loginbox">
    <img src="images/avatar.png" class="avatar">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
      <p>Username</p>
      <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="Enter Username">
      <p>Password</p>
      <input type="password" name="pswrd" placeholder="Enter Password">
      <input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login">

    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
      function check(form) {

        if (form.userid.value == "username" && form.pswrd.value == "password") {
          window.open('target.html')
        } else {
          alert("Error Password or Username")
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: i have tried this and it does nothing. but if i change it back to window.open it will load target.html in a new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
window.location.href = 'target.html';
```

Because the button is in a form, you must also cancel the default behavior of the event with `e.preventDefault()`.  Here's a full example:

```js
function check(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.form.userid.value == "username" && e.target.form.pswrd.value == "password") {
    window.location.href = 'target.html';
  } else {
    alert("Error Password or Username")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <img src="images/avatar.png" class="avatar">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="pswrd" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input type="submit" onclick="check(event)" value="Login">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried this and it does nothing. but if i change it back to window.open it will load  target.html in a new tab.

Comment: Oh, it's because you're submitting as a form.  This will cause the page to refresh instead of navigating.  Remove `type="submit"` or use `preventDefault` on the form event.

Comment: Yes that works!!  but if i remove type="submit" i lose the css on the submit button

Comment: I added  <script language="javascript">
      function check(form) {
        form.preventDefault() keeping type="submit" but the page keeps on refreshing

Comment: <input type="password" name="pswrd" placeholder="Enter Password">
      <input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login">

    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
      function check(form) {
        form.preventDefault()

        if (form.userid.value == "a" && form.pswrd.value == "a") {
          document.location.href = '/target.html';
        }
        else {
          alert("Error Password or Username")
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>

</body>

Comment: @Kay, have a look at the updated example above which uses `e.preventDefault`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you... it worked !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the type="submit" and use:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (form.userid.value == "username" && form.pswrd.value == "password") {
      window.open('target.html', '_self');
    } else {
      alert("Error Password or Username");
    } 
}, false);
```

Comment: The page only refreshes but does not open target.html

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login">

    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (form.userid.value == "a" && form.pswrd.value == "a") {

          window.open('target.html')

        } else {
          alert("Error Password or Username");
        }
      }, false);
    </script>